# Mysql - How to Restore database from '/var/lib/mysql/<database>' ubuntu

Tags: database, ubuntu

I want to restore my database from `/var/lib/mysql/<database>`.

I have tried with this process,

1) First, I stop `mysql` service.

2) After that, I copy my database from `/var/lib/mysql/<database>` old server to new server `/var/lib/mysql/<database>`.

3) Change all permission of that database

4) Then, I have restarted `MySQL` service.

but the result is I have seen all tables but when I click on the tables then there are no data in the table. In the database, I have around 374 tables, but in phpmyadmin I see only 13 tables.

And also table type change innoDb to memory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use mysqldump? An utility which comes with mysql to dump your data as sql queries and then run them on new database.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

But when you upload your data into new database check rows in table `core_config_data` with config paths `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`, values of these fields should be your current urls of host (in case domain of your store is changed).

Comment: Please read the question again.

Comment: What for? You need to transfer data from one database to another, i gave you option how to do this, you can use it or can not, why should i read your question again which is not associated with magento btw?